# position in an array

Tags: php, arrays

how could i find out that twoVal is at postion 1?

```
$arr = array('Cool Viski' => array('oneVal' => '169304',
                                   'twoVal' => '166678',
                                   'threeVal' => '45134'));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$position = array_search('twoVal', array_keys($arr['Cool Viski']));
```

Answer (score 0):

try array_keys hope it will help you out

```
$searchValue = "twoVal";
$keys = array_keys($array, $searchValue);
```